# null productIdentifier AND invalidproductIdentifier (In-App Purchase)

Tags: iphone, uikit, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have one product registered and cleared for sale in iTunes Connect.
I request the CORRECT product id but the SKProductsResponse object returns null productIdentifier and null invalidproductIdentifier.

What could be the problem?

- TOTAL PRODUCTS REGISTERED: 1
- PRODUCT IDs MATCH: YES
- CLEARED FOR PURCHASE: YES
- SDK: iOS4.0
- DEVICE OS: iOS4.0 installed on iPhone 3G
- APPSTORE ACCOUNT: Logged Out Of Real Account (Test Account Created)
- BUILD SETTINGS: Building under development and testing on device (For all of you saying "test using distrib" How are you supposed to test distrib on device?)

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for getting invalid Product ID is that: if you are running an App Store downloaded App on your device and then try to run a debug binary of the same App(built with a developer provisioning profile), you will get an invalid Product ID. So, make sure you delete the AppStore version of App before installing the debug binary.

I had to struggle for one full day to discover this hidden issue with IAP testing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just the productid rather than the full bundleid + productid?  I have heard mixed results but i'm having the problem of only seeing my products in the simulator but not the device (all criteria meets what you listed above)